# Configuring failover cluster on azure with two VMs on different tiers

Tags: sql-server, azure, failover

The question is related to configuring failover cluster on Azure VMs with SQL Server Enterprise version.

Is it possible to configure failover cluster with two machines like that:

- one high-spec PRIMARY server (VM + SQL Server)
- the second one on low-spec as the SECONDARY server (VM + SQL Server)

The main traffic will go to the PRIMARY as always but the SECONDARY will live there on low-spec just in case of downtime. That approach will save some money as it is more cost effective.

Can that be considered as bad/good/neutral practice? What are the other disadvantages apart from latency with syncing the data?

Note that this is failover cluster configuration only and it is set up to avoid the downtime when one of the servers goes down.

These articles are also very helpful, but there is no information related to my question:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr

Comment: you can do that no problem, the scale of the other VM doesn't matter THAT much if you can afford to scale it up when things go south

Comment: @4c74356b41 Not sure I'd give out such flippant advice. If a production server goes offline and a scaled-down secondary has to take over, and then can't handle the load, and then it too has to be taken offline to scale it up (since that's exactly what happens when scaling up), just imagine how far behind a system can fall. The only way to know this is to benchmark in normal state and fail state.

Comment: well, he already plans for that, so. i never said it was a great idea

Comment: @4c74356b41 - "*you can do that no problem*" followed by "*scale of the other VM doesn't matter THAT much*" - you pretty much said it was fine to do so.

Comment: well, I'm sorry if it looked like that, but what I meant is - if you are fine with such an awkward design

Comment: @4c74356b41, I am not planning anything. That was just a question. I need to count the costs in my calculations. This is only a failover cluster configuration, not mirroring. The thing is that I have high load only periodically happening on the primary and the secondary is only to keep the service alive and to avoid downtimes.